# ERROR TypeError: _co.function_name is not a function

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to use one HTML page (component) to another component. 
But I'm not able to find the click event.

[image]

**Dashboard.component :-**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  // replaces previous Http service
import { Http, Response , RequestOptions , Headers , URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule , FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { webserviceurl } from '../../url.constants';
import { AppAsideComponent } from '../../components/app-aside/app-aside.component';

export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit{

            constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {          
            }

            ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            }

            save_outage_index(){
              console.log('click');
            }

}
```

Dashboard.module.ts :-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
// import { AppAsideComponent } from './../../components/app-aside/app-aside.component';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';

import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';
// import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// import { GridModule } from '../../modules/grid.module';
// import { PanelModule } from '../../modules/panel.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    ChartsModule,
    BsDropdownModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ DashboardComponent,jqxGridComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**app-aside.component.html :-**

```
<button type="button" (click)="save_outage_index()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="background-color: #455D43;" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</button>
```

**app-aside.component.ts :-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-aside',
  templateUrl: './app-aside.component.html'
})
export class AppAsideComponent {

  constructor() { }
}
```

My question is how can I use **app-aside.component.ts** to **dashboard.component.ts**.

I have tried with this code in **dashboard.module.ts** as well as **dashboard.component.ts**.

```
import { AppAsideComponent } from './../../components/app-aside/app-aside.component';
```

And Use **AppAsideComponent** in declaration like this,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    ChartsModule,
    BsDropdownModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ AppAsideComponent,DashboardComponent,jqxGridComponent]
})
```

But it's still showing error that `co.save_outage_index is not a function`,

Comment: Where is your dashboard's component html?

Comment: @David. My dashboard's component html and app-aside component html both are in diffrent folder.

Comment: This example isnt 100% right, because if you want to use any function in all components you need to create a service which can be then provided. Read more about services and hoe to provide functions from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click handler `save_outage_index` needs to be defined in the same component as the template.

So you need to add the handler in the `app-aside.component.ts` file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-aside',
  templateUrl: './app-aside.component.html'
})
export class AppAsideComponent {

  constructor() { }


    save_outage_index(){
      console.log('click');
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to include the app-aside component in the dashboard, you need to add this html to your dashboard component's html

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<app-aside></app-aside>
```

If they are in the same module, there is no extra work. If not, you need to import the module containing the app-aside component inside your dashboard module

Comment: Ohk. Got it. Thank you it's working. I got the click event.  But I have to use some data of dashboard.component.ts in `save_outage_index()`. So, Is there any way that I can use this function inside dashboard.component.ts ? Is it a good practice ?

Comment: You should edit your question and show what exacly happens/not working

Comment: If you only want to use function not all component, then you should create a service and add it to providers.

Comment: @WebRence you should have a look at Input/Output properties, and EventEmitter then

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use component in another component you should do  :

1. Create component
2. Declare and Export it in module in your case :

   exports: [AppAsideComponent],
3. Use it like this in another component html : `<appaside></appaside>`

Edit :

**If you are trying to reach a component from another module you also need to import that module which is exporting that component.**

In your case you should add app-aside module into dashboard module.

Explanation :

If you have 2 modules with some components You have to declare these components in their parent modules. After that, you have to export components which will be used in other components. And if you want to reach another component from another module, you have to import that module in the module you want to use that component.

If that helps, please mark that is correct answer.